# Can you calculate the supplied heat given a p(V) - Diagram of a isobar process?

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

You are given an p(V) - Diagram like this:

[image: pV-Diagram]

Source: [How to calculate the efficiency from a $p$-$v$ diagram?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/333672/how-to-calculate-the-efficiency-from-a-p-v-diagram)

There you see two isothermal processes and two isochor processes.
For every given isothermial process I can exactly calculate the heat supplied by:

$\Delta U = \Delta W + \Delta Q = 0 \implies \int p(V)dV=- \Delta Q$

Now I assume an isobar process (not seen in the Diagram):
Again I know:

$\Delta U = \Delta W + \Delta Q \implies \int p(V)dV= \Delta U - \Delta Q$

But can I make a more precise statment? Can I calculate the heat supplied?
Same for isochor processes, where:

$\Delta U = \Delta Q$

I am wondering because I suppose that given this diagram (the circle), there should be an equilibrium of Energy supplied and Energy absorbed...

Thank you.

Comment: How is this an _isobaric_ process? I mean you say so in the title. I don't see how it is.

Comment: It is not. I just gave an example.

Comment: Neither process is isothermal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked source has an accepted answer that explains what you have to do very well. All you have to do is to calculate the temperature at the four points in your diagram by using the ideal gas equation.

As you can see, the first deviation ($PV^{1.1} ...$) is a polytropic process as it is of the form $PV^n = k$, where $k$ is some constant. The heat required to do such a polytropic process is given in that very link.

You can find the heat in that isochoric process by using the formula $Q=C_v \Delta T$, where $C_v$ is the specific heat capacity and $\Delta T$ is the temperature difference.

Comment: Thank you. But if I do not know the temperatures? I do not see the solution...

Comment: $T=PV/nr$, please review the ideal gas equations.

Comment: No problems! :)